# Image not loading in github pages

Tags: github-pages

Used VS Code to build a HTML/CSS site, uploaded the files into Github and the image isnt showing.

Looking for help to get this image to show up on the website.

Ive tried putting a . and then a .. before the slash but that didnt work.

I also checked to make sure the file names were the same after uploading in Github and for anything uppercase.

I did also get an error with Jekyll during the build in Github so maybe thats associated with this?

Below are pictures of the path in my documents and the HTML. Any help is appreciated!

[HTML image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fB9nr.png)

[Document path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vx0jV.png)

[Site picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntoMD.png)

[Jekyll error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8QM9.png)

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Does adding ./ to the beginning of the path work?

Comment: no, I saw that as a solution in another thread but that didnt work.

Comment: Have you tried including the project path? I believe since this isn't your root project you may need to supply that. Something like  `[github_project_name]/assets/images`